# always 403 Forbidden with Nginx .htpasswd

Tags: nginx

From looking at tutorials such as [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) it seems relatively easy to set up .htpasswd authentication.

Here's my HTTPS block which is how I'm accessing my site:

```
 server {
      listen 443;
      server_name potato;
      root /var/www/html;
      ssl on; 
      ssl_certificate      /srv/ssl/cert.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key  /srv/ssl/key.pem;  

      location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/nginx/.htpasswd;
      }

  }
```

I've gathered from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/zvvgna/create-htpasswd-file-for-nginx-without-apache) the following snippet to create the .htpasswd file:

```
 USERNAME=admin
 PASSWORD=password
 sudo printf "$USERNAME:$(openssl passwd -crypt $PASSWORD)\n" >> .htpasswd
```

This initially failed with a permission denied error, which I resolved by first creating an empty .htpasswd then granting myself permission via `sudo chown max:max .htpasswd`.

When I visit the website, I do see the Auth prompt, but I get a 403 error even I type in the correct password.

I have been fiddling with this for a while and am continuing to dig through google searches. But I'd appreciate any tips toward a likely source. It'd also be great if someone could show me a dependable way to diagnose the cause of the Auth failure.

In my access.log file I have entries like this:

```
73.170.238.232 - admin [05/Sep/2016:12:03:34 -0700] "GET /musicker/dist/ HTTP/1.1" 403 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8350.68.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

but I don't see much useful information in there. You can see I'm trying to access the website at `/musicker/dist/`, and in Nginx my   `location /` block is catching this and adding auth_basic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thankfully I figured this out not long after the posting the question, but I think the following information would be available to others looking to solve similar problems:

The relevant logs are not in `access.log`, but rather in `error.log`.

Running this showed me that the `.htaccess` file was not in the expected location. Then I moved it to the correct location and was able to authenticate OK.

Comment: Same problem here! Thanks 

Comment: I was making a similar mistake, except I was using a Docker container where the htpasswd file was a Docker secret which hadn't been created inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer is already here, I will try to explain a bit more for someone who does not get the above one.

Well, I too get the **`403 Forbidden`** and on checking the logs:

> 2020/01/02 07:46:19 [error] 21521#21521: *258843 open()
>   "/etc/ngnix/.htpasswd" failed (2: No such file or directory), client:
>   10.3.11.168, server: localhost, request: "GET /reports/ HTTP/1.0", host: "www.example.com"

Though I had saved the `.htpasswd` exactly at the location `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` but it could not be find it.

Then I moved the .htpasswd to `/var/www/html/.htpasswd` and it resolved my error.

Thanks!